# IPA Keyboard userscript for you!

Tags: discussion

Apparently, you folks could do with an IPA Keyboard<sup>1</sup>. So, [here you go!](https://stackapps.com/questions/3828/ipa-keyboard-for-linguistics-se)

[image: enter link description here]

The most useful feature (IMO) are the keyboard shortcuts, you may want to check out how to use them (details on the page I linked to above)

Please let me know of any features you want or bugs. The script auto-updates, so you need not worry about re-installing it (things should sync in ~ a day)

A few known bugs:

- The editor does not refresh the preview when you type via the IPA Keyboard. To refresh the preview, tap <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (or just type some alphanumeric character) while typing in the textarea.
- There sometimes is a delay when loading a keyboard. Clicking the schwa again fixes this.

I'm also planning to work on making the keyboard draggable.

With some luck, SE may incorporate a better version of this into the editor for this site (Similar to how UX.SE has an inbuilt Balsamiq editor).

<sup>Thank @Alenanno for this, he's the one who mentioned it to me :)</sup>

Comment: This is great! It works very well. The only thing is that I can't get it to work with Noscript, if you are familiar with that: it is a Firefox extension that allows you to block Javascript selectively and do other things. I have set it to allow Javascript from Stack Exchange and from Github; I have tried adding Github to the XSS and ABE exceptions, but I couldn't get it to work (perhaps I'm doing the XSS and ABE things wrong). I really need Noscript, and it only works for me with Noscript disabled...but I encourage your project!

Comment: @Cerberus: Hmm, I can't get a fix to work in userscript form, but here's a bookmarklet: https://raw.github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/master/StackExchange/Extensions/IPAKeyboard/NoscriptBookmarklet.txt . To use it, first ensure that View>Toolbars>Bookmarks is ticked. Now, right click on the bookmark bar, select "new bookmark". Give it a name "IPA Keyboard", copy paste the data from the link above to the "location" field, and ensure that the "load in sidebar" box is unticked. Now, clicking the button on an SE site will add the schwa button.

Comment: Yay, it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For simple IPA chunks, there are also these keyboard generators:

- http://westonruter.github.com/ipa-chart/keyboard/
- http://linguistlist.org/unicode/ipa.html

and English phoneme charts like [this one](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf), where one can copy the appropriate symbol for pasting.

**NOTE:** These all assume that your [Text (or Character) Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is set to [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) (UTF-8).

Comment: My keyboard is based on http://ipa.typeit.org/full/. That one has a few extra features, may be useful :)

Comment: One of the nicer things that keyboard generators support is allowing you to attach arbitrary diacritics, which are usually combining marks, to base glyphs. That is something you really cannot do just by grabbing things with your mouse.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Linux, another option is to use the IBus "Other - ipa-x-sampa" input method. You type in a transcription in [X-SAMPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-SAMPA) (see the article for charts), and it will be converted into Unicode IPA.

Type

```
/I_xg"z{mp.l= || "lajk "DIs/
```

to get

> /ɪ̽ɡˈzæmp.l̩ ‖ ˈlajk ˈðɪs/

Comment: That looks... complicated. :D

Answer (score 1):

Great job! :D I think someday we could ask SE to implement it for good natively. :D