# Should we pin an IPA chart and a link to a multi-script keyboard on the help page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Since it is the *Linguistics* SE and for those who don't have access to ([IPA Keyboard userscript for you!](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/454/ipa-keyboard-userscript-for-you)) or don't know about it, I think it must have a standard IPA chart and a link to a multi-script keyboard (like lexilogos) on the help page or the tour page.

Comment: Do you know that this is technically doable, and if so can you elaborate on what you want?

Comment: @user6726 1) When I ask a question / write an answer there is a semi-orange floating rectangular help/guide box to the right, if possible could it also have an IPA guide? 2) On the help / tour guide page or the box can we have a link to a multi script keyboard (like lexilogos) (just a link) ... So my point being I don't think it's something that needs to be hard coded in and I don't know how to do it if so